# How can i insert a new row between two rows that exsisting in a table in MySql Workbench with sql query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

my table1 has 4 records and my table2 has 5 records. i want to insert 1 record before second row in table1 and
column (id) in table1 should be sorted again from 1 to 5 .
is there any query to do this for me? 
my sql database is MySQL Workbench :)

```
column : id      date      name   
row1   : 1     saturday     Moj
row2   : 2      monday    Alireza
```

now i'd like to add a row between this two rows and something like this :

```
column : id      date      name   
row1   : 1     saturday     Moj
row2   : 2     sunday      Zahra
row3   : 3     monday     Alireza
```

i found something like this, but it doesnt work for me :

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE table1 SET id = id + 1 WHERE id >= 3 order by id DESC;
INSERT INTO table1 (id, value) VALUES (3, 300);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: 'insert 1 record' - which record would that be then? Sample data and expected result would help.

Comment: You want to change the IDs of all the rows after the one you're inserting? That's usually not a good idea because of foreign key relationships with other tables.

Comment: But if you really want to do this, add 1 to the IDs of all rows with `id >= 2`, then insert a new with with the ID 2.

Comment: You have to do this with 2 queries, you can't do it all at once.

Comment: i edited the post plz see again @P.Salmon

Comment: What has table 2 to do with it?

Comment: I don't think it's going to be a problem at all with foreign key @Barmar

Comment: they have relationship together , and i join them in my java code @P.Salmon

Comment: because of column(id) has auto increment i dont think it works with this [add 1 to the IDs of all rows with id >= 2, then insert a new with with the ID 2] @Barmar

Comment: I think there is no way to do that only in columns can be rearrange but rows are not

Comment: @Mozhdeh7 Why wouldn't it work? auto-increment only specifies the default value of the ID column, but you can still set it explicitly to some other value.

Comment: The solution you show works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fFF5RKPmzLnWdiMympk6yZ/0